# Insidebar strategy at tradingview

Tags: pine-script

Im trying to make a simple insidebar strategy @tradingview but no success.

the stragety logic would be:

if there is a insidebar, then:
**buy** if price hits the **high of the insidebar** (takeprofit 2 points stoploss 5 points)
**sell** if price hits the **low of the insidebar** (takeprofit 2 points, stoploss 5 points)

I tried every combination of things in the manual but I guess I'm a failure when it comes to programing.
Could anyone give some help?

his is what I did so far:

```
//@version=4 strategy("test")
insidebar = (high[1] > high[0] and low[1] < low[0])
if (insidebar)
strategy.entry("buy", strategy.long)
strategy.exit("exit", "buy", profit = 4, loss = 10) plot(strategy.equity)
```

Comment: Hi braid and welcome. Please refrain from using self-deprecating language, since it's unfair to yourself and won't help your question or the community. Your question would be improved if you could share the code with one of the ideas you tried.

Comment: Hello, this is what I did so far://@version=4
strategy("test")
insidebar = (high[1] > high[0] and low[1] < low[0])
if (insidebar)
    strategy.entry("buy", strategy.long)
    strategy.exit("exit", "buy", profit = 4, loss = 10)
plot(strategy.equity)

Comment: Haha I suggest you include that within your answer! Look for the "edit" button. Also notice you can format text as code, which will look better.

Comment: done! thanks, my bad.